# Is there a way to change the default dnsPolicy without modifying every PodSpec?

Tags: kubernetes

I am looking for a way to use `dnsPolicy = "Default"` in kubernetes clusters I manage.

The [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pod-s-dns-policy) mention that

> DNS policies can be set on a per-pod basis. [...] These policies are
>   specified in the dnsPolicy field of a Pod Spec.

Changing every PodSpec is a very costly operation for me. Is there another way to change the default [dnsPolicy](https://v1-7.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/v1.7/#podspec-v1-core) parameter globally for the cluster ?

Maybe via kubelet ?

Comment: What version of Kubernetes you use?

Comment: @nickrak i am at kubernetes 1.6. Both on the kubelet and apiserver side

Comment: Do you want to change `dnsPolicy`  for each Pod in the cluster or only for a few specific ones ?

Comment: I found a similar question to yours with a comprehensive answer: [How to set DNS Policy at Cluster Level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54677687/kubernetes-how-to-set-dns-policy-at-cluster-level).
Does it answer your question ?